# Счётчик посещений страницы

Tags: php, yii2, счетчики

**Есть ли какой-то адекватный модуль для подсчёта уникальных посетителей страниц сайта?** Искал по гитхабу и интернету в целом, ничего достойного не нашёл.

Тратить свое время на написание с нуля не хочется. Яндекс метрика и прочее не подходят. Нужно чтобы всё сохранялось только в базу данных сайта, при этом чтобы считало адекватно, отсеивая неуникальные просмотры.

Проект на yii2. Если есть что-то из расширений для него, то будет классно.

Под адекватным подсчётом понимается следующее:

- Фильтрация уникальности(ip и другие факторы)
- Фильтрация посещений от поисковых систем
- Точность подсчёта
- Хранение информации в базе mysql или другой БД.

Comment: На сайте хочешь аналог `google analytics`, трудный вопрос.

Comment: Я хочу понять нет ли уже монструозного готового решения, которое не использует чужие БД для хранения информации о уникальных посетителях.

Comment: Уникальность посетителя решается по браузеру. надо после захода на сайт в `cookies` написать какую то уникальную переменную, заранее посмотрев если его уже нет. и так будет тебе уникальный посетитель, но если человек очистит свою историю браузера, или зайдет другим то он уже для тебя будет уникальным новым.

Comment: И еще все ровно ты все эти данные даешь и гуглу и яндексу, так что не пойму зачем в собственной базе?

Comment: Недавно как раз разбирался с google analytics. Там же целая библиотека написанная на JS с кучей методов и разными плагинами. Причём зачастую в самом руководстве специально указывается что самим лучше не пилить, т.к. всё это очень сложно (например междоменное отслеживание). Это я к тому, что большая часть на клиенте. Плюс отслеживание событий и прочее.

Comment: Потому что манипулировать с данными, которые находятся на стороннем сервере, получать списки ip адресов, user-agent`ов, число просмотров для страниц в реал-тайме довольно проблематично, это при использовании гугл аналитики или яндекс метрики. Поэтому и задался вопросом поиска существующего решения или придётся долго писать свое, учитывая все параметры, как раз вроде ограничений подсчёта просмотров поисковиков и прочего.

Comment: Проще застрелиться, извините. Покопайте всё таки их API https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008004?hl=ru

Comment: Ладно, буду тогда делать сам. Не вижу трудностей в этом, просто дольше, чем использовать готовое решение. В библиотеке гугла много различных модулей, они не просто подсчитывают число посещений, а также много других данных. А мне требуется лишь число уникальных посещений, но без учёта поисковиков и адекватный отсев повторов и ботов